# Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql

How can I overcome it?

```sql
select * 
from clothorder 
ORDER BY orderId DESC 
LIMIT 1 
where custId='haikal@gmail.com';
```

Comment: The `Where` clause should go BEFORE the `Order By`

Answer (score 2):

The where clause goes before the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clothorder 
WHERE custId='haikal@gmail.com' 
ORDER BY orderId DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```